# How many drops you need to make. You are allowed to break 2 eggs in the process

Tags: logical-deduction, optimization

You are given 2 eggs.

- You have access to a 100-story building.
   Eggs can be very hard or very fragile meaning it may break if dropped from the first floor or may not even break if dropped from 100th floor.
- Both eggs are identical.
- You need to figure out the highest floor of a 100-story building an egg can be dropped without breaking.
- How many drops you need to make. You are allowed to break 2 eggs in the process

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could:

**First Egg**

> Take the first egg and drop it from the first floor, if it breaks you know that you cant drop from any higher than the first floor, if not you can keep going one floor at a time

**Second Egg**

> Drop the second egg from the 5th floor. If it doesnt break it rules out floors 2-4.

**Doing this**

> You could continue this process until the second egg eventually breaks making your range for the first egg much smaller. When the first egg eventually breaks you know thats the highest it can go.

Comment: because both eggs are identical, this is not an optimal strategy. The first egg is dropped from floor 13. You only drop from floor one if that egg breaks, otherwise it is a waste to drop

Comment: @micsthepick Why specifically floor 13?